# How do I get a list of all languages that my Windows Forms application has been localized to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I have localized localized a Form into two language by setting the Localizable property to True and setting the Language from (Default) to (Dutch(Netherlands)), and I changed the control texts.

Visual Studio generated the resource files and compiles them into the application.

I need to get a simple list of all the languages that my form has been localized into. Currently it would be just two English and Dutch, but more may come. I need to programatically get a list of "what languages my application is localized into". Do I look into the resource files or use ResourceManager or what?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did my comment thread go? Me and another person were having a whole conversation here, and I come back the next day, and the comments are all gone. wtf?

Answer (score 1):

For every language the form is localized to, you would get a satellite assembly within a folder. The folder name would be the specific culture. Ex: en-GB for English (United Kingdom).
These folders would be created in the Application's base directory.

Populate the folder names in the Listbox, when a user selects an item store it in the config.
And in the Main, before Form load set the current culture and current UI culture.

Comment: Unluckily .NET does not offer a batter what than this. I usually look for satellite assemblies too.